# How to differentiate between event saved through my app and event saved by using calendar app using EventKit?

Tags: ios, swift4, eventkit, ekcalendar

I have successfully saved the events of my application to local calendar using `Eventkit` but now I want to delete the events that I have saved using my application only.
But the below code give me list of all events saved on calendar but I just want to delete my own saved event. How can I do that?

```
 let predicate = eventStore.predicateForEvents(withStart: start, end: endDate, calendars: [calendar])       
 let events = eventStore.events(matching: predicate)
```

Answer (score 2):

When saving events to calendar you can store `EKEvent`'s [eventIdentifier](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/eventkit/ekevent/1507437-eventidentifier) property.

And when you want to delete events that were created by you, you can query them by identifiers.

**Note:** store `eventIdentfier` only after calling `eventStore.save(...)` method.

Comment: Thanks yes doing same by saving array of saved events identifier in userdefalut and fetch those when I want to delete :)

Answer (score 0):

You can only remove event by comparing Event Title with fetched events:

```
    var allEvents: [EKEvent] = []

    let eventStore = EKEventStore()
    let calendars = eventStore.calendars(for: .event)

    for calendar in calendars {

        // end date (about) one year from now
        let endDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 60*60*24*365)

        let predicate = eventStore.predicateForEvents(withStart: Date(), end: endDate as Date, calendars: [calendar])

        let events = eventStore.events(matching: predicate)

        allEvents.append(contentsOf: events)

    }

    for event in allEvents {
        print(event.title, "in", event.calendar.title)
    }
```

Comment: Things will be better if you include some explanation along with your code.